# What are the specifications of the free Meteor server?

Tags: meteor, cloud-hosting

What are the specification of the free server where my meteor app runs when I do this.

```
meteor deploy myapp.meteor.com
```

Specification in terms of

```
Storage size
Max bandwidth
Max Connections
Processing limits
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

At the moment from what they're saying on the [meteor-talk](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/meteor-talk/9rmHQiOTMMs) group, there aren't any enforced limits of any sort. Your app just sort of scales itself alongside all the others hosted there.

There is only one thing though, if your app isn't used/has no visits for a few consecutive hours its 'killed'. When someone visits it next time its put back up (of course the end user wont notice this, to them its as if it were up all along)

But what it means is background processes that you use/cron type tasks don't work well because the meteor deploy server will kill your app's task silently until the next web request comes along.

Comment: Interesting, can you give a citation for that?

Comment: The meteor-talk link I referenced has info on the no-strict limits. For the meteor killing apps behind the scenes see your logs via `meteor logs xx.meteor.com` or https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/meteor-talk/0LcW-dzJtzU by the core devs

Comment: so i can create my own big apps on meteor.com how about like youtube or 9gag, so every users can upload big size file to my meteor apps?

Comment: As with before they haven't given strict limits of any sort but if you use alot/use it in an abusive manner they'll likely get in touch with you @yozawiratama

Comment: "When someone visits it next time its put back up (of course the end user wont notice this, to them its as if it were up all along)" -- this doesn't seem to be true anymore; when I return to my test app after a long while, I get a splash page saying the app is winding up again, so the user will definitely notice this.